# JavaScript and CSS not loading in Azure PHP (Codeigniter) Web Application

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed PHP Codeigniter Web Application in Microsoft Azure Web App. I have deployed the app successfully but it is not loading styles as it is doing in local server. Here is my new web app screenshot: [image: Azure Web Application]

When I run it locally it displays the landing page like this: [image: Local server]

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?
I would really appreciate your help.
Than you.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the network console of your browser? Do the file locations match?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I have no experience in php codeigniter and was just deploying in azure for learning purposes.

Comment: checking the network tab in your browser doesn't have to do anything with Codeigniter and php... (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) its probably a https - http conflict... (it's not allowed to mix protocols...)

Comment: I have changed my Web.config file and I think it's working fine now.